# Как создать структуру frontend на Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, django, frontend

Как организовать обыкновенный фронтэнд с привычными Bower, gulp, SASS, React.js, работая на Django (Python 3)?

Comment: Это нифига не обыкновенный фронтенд. Обыкновенный фронтенд в джанге есть из коробки — HTML-шаблоны в папке templates, CSS и JS в папке static :)

Comment: @andreymal так я так с папочкой js и css в 2012 делал. Сейчас мне в тренде хочется быть.

Comment: А по теме вопроса всё же не до конца понятно, какой именно фронтенд вы хотите. Если SPA — то делайте его как обычно отдельно от джанги, а джанга пусть выступает просто как API. Если не SPA — а как вы тогда применяете реакт? Я в общем-то не очень компетентен в «трендах», но по-моему всё-таки нужно больше подробностей

Comment: Кстати, от трендов вы всё-таки отстаёте. bower/gulp/react был в тренде в каком-нибудь 2013-м, а сейчас в тренде yarn/webpack/vue :)

Comment: Бэкендерский фреймворк Django никакого отношения не имеет к тому, что вы перечислили. Отделяйте мух от котлет.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev но как не имеет отношения? Я же буду использовать тот самый frontend stack в Django шаблонах!

Comment: @Constantor всё перечисленное не имеет никакого отношения к Django шаблонам

Comment: @Constantor если вы используете шаблонизатор Django вместе с React, значит вы не понимаете React и не умеете им пользоваться.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev если бы я хотел использовать vue или angular вы бы ответили то же самое?

Comment: @Constantor да.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо.